# add column in datagridview

Tags: vb.net, excel, datagridview

I use vb.net with excel

I have a buttom "get the name of the column from worksheet" with a combobox

this is the code of the button:

```
Private Sub Button7_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button7.Click
    Dim Excols As New Dictionary(Of Integer, String)
    Form2.xlWorkSheet = CType(Form2.xlWorkBook.Sheets(Form2.ComboBox1.Text), Excel.Worksheet)
    Form2.xlWorkSheet.Activate()

    With Form2.xlWorkSheet
        Dim LastCol As Integer = Form2.xlWorkSheet.Cells(1,
        Form2.xlWorkSheet.Columns.Count).End(XlDirection.xlToLeft).Column
        For x As Integer = 2 To LastCol
            Excols.Add(x, Form2.xlWorkSheet.Cells(1, x).value.ToString)
        Next
        ComboBox2.DataSource = New BindingSource(Excols, Nothing)
        ComboBox2.ValueMember = "Key"
        ComboBox2.DisplayMember = "Value"
        AddHandler ComboBox2.SelectedIndexChanged, AddressOf   
        ComboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged
    End With
End Sub
```

this is the code of the combobox:

```
Private Sub ComboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Form2.xlWorkSheet = CType(Form2.xlWorkBook.Sheets(Form2.ComboBox1.Text), Excel.Worksheet)
    Form2.xlWorkSheet.Activate()
    Form2.xlApp.Visible = True
    Dim key As String =          
    CStr(DirectCast(ComboBox2.SelectedItem, KeyValuePair(Of Integer, String)).Key)
    Dim value As String =             
    DirectCast(ComboBox2.SelectedItem, KeyValuePair(Of Integer, String)).Value
    Dim DoesSheetExists As Boolean = False
    For Each xs In Form2.xlApp.Sheets
        If xs.Name = value Then
            DoesSheetExists = True
    Next

    If DoesSheetExists = True Then
        MsgBox("Sheet already exists", CType(MessageBoxIcon.Error, MsgBoxStyle))
    Else
        With Form2.xlWorkSheet
            Dim lastrow As Integer = Form2.xlWorkSheet.Cells.Rows.End(XlDirection.xlDown).Row
            Dim colletter As String = ColumnIndexToColumnLetter(CInt(key))
            exWS2 = DirectCast(Form2.xlWorkBook.Sheets.Add, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)
            exWS2.Name = value
            Form2.xlWorkSheet.Range("A1:A" & lastrow.ToString).Copy(exWS2.Range("A1"))
            Form2.xlWorkSheet.Range(colletter & "1:" & colletter & lastrow.ToString).Copy(exWS2.Range("B1"))
            exWS2.Range("A1").Font.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Blue)
            exWS2.Range("B1").Font.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Blue)
            exWS2.Range("A1").Interior.ColorIndex = 8
            exWS2.Range("B1").Interior.ColorIndex = 8
            exWS2.Range("A2:A" & lastrow.ToString).Interior.ColorIndex = 20
            exWS2.Range("A1:A" & lastrow.ToString).HorizontalAlignment =       -4108

            exWS2.Range("B1:B" & lastrow.ToString).HorizontalAlignment = -4108
            exWS2.Range("A1").Font.Name = "Times New Roman"
            exWS2.Range("B1").Font.Name = "Times New Roman"
            exWS2.Range("B1").Font.FontStyle = "Gras"
            exWS2.Range("A1").Font.FontStyle = "Gras"
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

What i want is to add every time when i select a column , it will be added to a datagridview

this is my column that i want to add to the datagridview

help me please

Comment: Did you have a question?  Please read [Ask].

Comment: Simply I want to display in the datagrid or other tool the table column I select in the combobox

Comment: Please learn how to format your code next time.

Comment: i'm sorry :(    would you give me an idea or exemple for my question !!